# How to prevent PyAutoGui from activating emojis

Tags: pyautogui

When using PyAutoGui in Discord typing automatically brings up emojis how can I disable this?  I've disabled it on the keyboard via preferences for Mac and also disabled it in Discord.  But when a certain element is typed it still brings up the emojis.

My code is:

```
        pg.keyDown('option')
        pg.press('up')
        pg.keyUp('option')
        pg.press('tab')
        time.sleep(1)
        pg.write('this is a type test')
```

Answer (score 0):

pyAutoGui doesn't have an option to paste so I ended up doing this with:

```
import pyperclip

pyperclip.copy('this is me here')
pg.keyDown('command')
pg.press('v')
pg.keyUp('command')
```